# Why is my list not showing in a floating container in ST2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm writing some test code and would like to show a list in a floating container. The test code is not working. Can anyone have a look to see if there is anything I am missing:

```
var p = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    xtype: 'panel',
    scrollable: true,
    centered: true,
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    items: [
    {
        xtype:"container",
        layout: {
           type: 'vbox'
        },
        items: [            
            {
                xtype: "list",
                itemTpl: '{title},{author}',
                flex: 1,
                store: {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    fields : ['title', 'author'],
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'jsonp',
                        url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }   
    ]
});
Ext.Viewport.add(p);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simply because you are trying to put a list inside a FormPanel.
Try to use a container instead, and, in addition, if you only need to put a list inside it, don't use a "vbox" layout but a fit one.

```
var p = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    centered: true,
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [            
        {
            xtype: "list",
            ...
```